# Does SimplePie automatically remove invalid images and links?

Tags: hyperlink, rss, simplepie

I am working on a web application and want to use SimplePie for parsing a lot of RSS feeds.

One problem is that I want to know if SimplePie automatically removes all the dead links while parsing RSS feeds. So that the final output of the RSS feed doesn't have any invalid links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not. In order to do so, you'd have to send a HEAD request for every link in the feed. This is too expensive for SimplePie to do, so you'll need to find code to do that on your own. Try [this example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244506/how-do-i-check-for-valid-not-dead-links-programatically-using-php).